# Is there a way to simulate permissions assigned to a file without applying them to the file?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

The command `apt-get` allows me to simulate the installation or the removal of a package by including the switch/option/flag `-s` e.g. `apt-get -s install {package_name}`. Am I able to emulate a similar action when using `chmod`?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. Either a file has a set of permissions or it doesn't.

What are you trying to accomplish?

If you want to be able to trace file access see this SO answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205815/monitoring-file-and-directory-access-on-linux